# Javascript closure and memory issues

Tags: javascript

```
//Following function add new table entry to table
//and return interface which has function which uses closure to access and update the table
var _newRow  = (function(){
    var _interface = {
        updateName: null,
        updateProgress: null,
        actionLinkButton : null,//<a> tag used for user aciton to perform on UI like delete, hide, show etc.
        ..
        ..
        ..
    };
    var tr = createTr();    
    var tdName = createTd();
    _inteface.updateName = function(newName){
        tdName.innerHTML = newName;
    }
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..  
    return _interface;
})(tblObject);

//maintaining the array of all the rows as per row number
rowArray[rowNo] = _newRow;
..
..
//using the row array to update the entries
rowArray[rowNo].updateProgress('read');
```

Above is the pattern i have used to update the dynamically added rows on the client end. What i do is to while adding row to the table create _interface, return it and store it as per row number.

However for this i have used closure means many alive objects. I would like to know is this correct way ? Is there better approach that this ? What profiling tools i can use to know how much memeory this code is using ? How can i ensure that closures are cleared properly when they are not needed ?

Comment: Have a look at http://getfirebug.com/ which is a plugin for FireFox or the build in profiler in any Webkit browser(Google Chrome, Safari).

Comment: Yes, i am using it. But its not indicating memory and heap size and stuff. Also no indications on wrong practices or memory size increase. Is there some other tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has a garbage collector which will collect stray objects and deallocate them for you automatically. There is no way to control when or how.

What may prevent objects/closures from being garbage collected is when you have globally accessible objects referencing functions with lexical scope. Make sure you detach all values you don't use (for instance, remove them from the DOM). If you're sure there is no way to access the values they will eventually be garbage collected.

To identify memory leaks it's important to not optimize prematurely, you can monitor the memory usage of your web browser. If it isn't noticeable there then you probably don't need to worry about it. You may want to simulate a lot of operations in your app, to see what the state might look like after the app has been running for a long time.

But generally, don't worry about memory usage. It is in my experience very rarely an issue.